# How can I call componentDidUpdate() with componentDidMount in react-native redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am fetching data from API in react-native redux but when I call `componentDidMount()` function, It fetches data and It runs once at a time, but when I call `componentDidMount()` with `componentDidUpdate()` for updating data that I have changed in settings pages and saved in redux state then my emulator gets hanged and `componentDidUpdate()` function runs a lot of time at a second like loop.

Is there any method to stop it and it should run once at a time? `if else` condition?

What is the real method to call `componentDidMount() with componentDidUpdate()`?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: it worked now brother. with if else prevProps

Comment: Good. However, as InfectedMushroom said, you should never call componentDidMount in your componentDidUpdate function. You might want to change that code in order to avoid potential bugs.

Comment: brother, i am not calling didUpdate in didMount, i am calling them separate, the reason of loop is that i was not checking prevProps.

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount()` only runs at once while the component is in the mounting phase. 
Calling `componentDidMount()` inside `componentDidUpdate()` is an anti pattern and would result in the infinite loop which causing you an infinite loop.
If you need to update the page with the data you have just fetched from the endpoint you have to call `componentDidUpdate()` method.

And if you need to check for the difference between the `prevProps` and `this.props` before running another update on the page.

Edit: You can refer to this page to check different life cycles you have to work in the react.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: yeah it worked now with if else check prevProps. thanks brother.